# FetchS3Object Issue

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I'm setting up an nifi process to download files from S3 bucket from a 3 node cluster systems.  I have a `ListS3 > FetchS3Object > PutHDFS`.  The `ListS3` get the list of the files, but the `FetchS3Object` is reporting the issue below.  I'm connecting to the S3 bucket via a private url and able to connected via aws cli on primary node using the same url to list\download of files on the linux system.  Below you will also find the configure for the `ListS3` and `FetchS3Object`.  Please let me know if I'm missing anything in the current config and what can be causing the issue.

Thanks!

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoxtA.jpg)]

I checked s3 bucket permission and all is good.  I also verified that I can list and download files using aws cli without any issue. .